# Отсутствует библиотека NAudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, naudio

Мне нужна библиотека NAudio, но ее нет.

Я пишу

```
using NAudio.Wave;
```

На NAudio выдает ошибку что "Типа или имени NAudio не найдено".

Два вопроса:

1. Как подключить библиотеку NAudio?
2. Если нет, то может есть какая то альтернатива этой библиотеке?

Comment: Где именно ее нет?

Comment: Пойду отпишусь разработчикам, что их библиотеки больше нет.

Comment: Я пишу using NAudio.Wave.на NAudio выдает ошибку что "Типа или имени NAudio не найдено"

Comment: А скачать библиотеку и почитать документацию на нее вы пробовали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Библиотеку нужно скачать и подключить к проекту перед использованием:

Откройте консоль управления пакетами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и выполните там команду установки [nuget-пакета NAudio](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio/):

```
Install-Package NAudio
```

Comment: Спасибо за адекватный ответ! Сейчас попробую

Comment: Отключенный ClearType в 2015-м году. Ещё сохранились консерваторы. О_О (Ссылка на Мете всплыла.)

Comment: @Discord это скрин с https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console :). у меня же вообще темная тема :)

Answer (score 0):

Проект --> Управление пакетами NuGet --> Найти и установить NAudio.

Answer (score -1):

В меню инструментов (сверху) заходите в сервис/диспечер пакетов NuGet/обзор, вбиваете `Naudio` и скачиваете.